# Is bleach residue (after evaporation) safe?

Tags: bleach

I have been preparing bleach disinfectant lately in a spray bottle and have been spraying on my couch, door mat, door knots, etc...
I don't rinse it... So I assume there is bleach residue left after evaporation. Is it safe to leave the residue?

I felt some very mild burn like feeling on my arms when putting my arms on my couch lately; I don't know if this is some kind of placebo effect or if it is real.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK most bleach contains NaOH and NaClO. The hypochlorite (which is the bit that does the bleaching) breaks down to common salt and free oxygen. The hydroxide doesn't. So it's possible you are experiencing some kind of chemical burn.

Comment: The hydroxide *will* "break down" (but possibly at a slower rate). It will react with [carbon dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) in the air and form [sodium carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate)  (a much weaker base than NaOH). A perhaps more well-known case is for calcium hydroxide (Ca(OH)2) used as [lime paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewash#Use_as_paint), reacting to form  calcium carbonate (Ca2CO3).

Comment: The NaOH they add to it is to prolong shelf life. And the reaction by which sodium hypochlorite is reduced to sodium chloride consumes protons, producing even more hydroxide, so it's indeed possible that residual alkali is causing the irritation the OP is describing. Reaction with CO2 is not incredibly fast. Same as for my comment above about the hypochlorite itself, I would recommend some caution with such effective but quite harsh chemicals.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. I'm new here :) And, this is not meant as a criticism of the OP, this is really a chemistry question, isn't it?

Comment: ok thx for the replies but is the residue safe or not?

Comment: I have stopped spraying on the couch.. only on my door knots, light switches, sink, toilet and sink handles

Comment: Yes, probably a good idea not to use it on fabric or surfaces that may absorb it. On other (hard, non-absorbing) surfaces, I would say let it react for a few minutes and then wipe it off or rinse it with water. Make sure it doesn't seep into the electrical bits of light switches. And note that it will corrode (oxidize) metal if left there indefinitely (even chloride alone promotes corrosion, and here you're using a strong oxidizing reagent, so...).

Comment: @timpin perhaps at the interface between chemistry and medical science; the OP is asking about some possible consequences of the use of bleach on his health. In any case, I found the question here and thought it'd be helpful to answer, as the OP needed to know what to do. Practicality over excessive formality.

Comment: what can i use on my couch (cloth and semi leather) for sanitizing?

Comment: I will also stop spraying electric switches then cuz I think some are getting inside... I will just use a cloth damped in diluted bleach and lightly rub the electric switches...less convenient than spraying but I think safer.. will only spray door knots, sink, toilet and sink handles now lol and my bin

p.s. I am so paranoid these days :( and doing stuff without thinking

Answer (score 1):

> In its manufacturing process, hypochlorite bleach begins as salt and water. After use, the compound breaks down mainly into salt and water during or quickly after use.

So it's table salt left behind, NaCl, as well as the similar NaClO3 and NaOCl.

https://www.infectioncontroltoday.com/environmental-hygiene/dispelling-myths-about-bleach-odors

Comment: Is the effect the same if the applied bleach on a surface is not diluted in water? i.e. the compound would breaks down  mainly into salt and water?

Comment: You can only buy diluted bleach, usually at 5%

Comment: Yes, but I mean, usually in the bottle's instruction says "1/2 of bleach in 16 liters of water" if one uses pure bleach (no mixing it with water), then the bleach will break down mainly into salt and water?

Comment: Yes, it's made from Salt sand decomposes to Salt

Comment: I see,, thanks.

Comment: As a chemist, I would not be so sure that bleach, diluted or not, decomposes so quickly after application to a surface. It depends on what it finds to react with and many other factors. I would definitely never use undiluted (3-6%) bleach on anything I don't rinse afterwards. And even with diluted bleach, I would let it react and wipe it off before resting on it. But by all means, it's my favourite disinfectant and I recommend it over anything else. Only, consider that it's so powerful precisely because it's so reactive. So, caution is advised.

Comment: BTW, there are ways to test for residual bleach. Iodide+starch strips typically. They are sold online, or you can make them yourself if you can get hold of potassium or sodium iodide.

Comment: Those are pretty misleading claims from an employee of the Kolorx company. In reality"the Hooker process [...] is the only large-scale industrial method of sodium hypochlorite production. In the process, sodium hypochlorite (NaClO) and sodium chloride (NaCl) are **formed when chlorine is passed into cold dilute *sodium hydroxide* solution**." (Wikipedia) Of course how it's made has little to do with how it's used, but that "oh it's safe because it's made from salt" opening doesn't bode well for the integrity of the rest of the article.

Comment: Yes you can make it straight from salt too, if you have ozone available. (And that's not a "safe ingredient" either, if you want to follow their logic.)

Comment: Are people saying this needs to be moved to the chemistry.se ?